# NHibernate - Should all child objects be updated when parent is saved, when cascade is save-update?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a bidirectional one to many relationship defined with cascade="all" defined on both ends in the mapping and inverse="true" on the one-to-many end.

When I call SaveOrUpdate a new entity the it correctly inserts a row into the parent table, then inserts all the child objects in the child table.

However, if I have an existing entity and update some properties of the child objects (say alter some string properties) then call SaveOrUpdate on the parent entity, it only updates the information in the parent table. I was expecting it to update all the child entities also.

Is this the expected behaviour? Do I need to manually update all the child objects myself? I'm not sure if I've messed something up in my mappings (in which case I'll add them to the question) or if this is how NHibernate is supposed to behave.

Edit: found the error; problem exists between keyboard and chair as usual.

Comment: The children entities are *proxy* objects. NH will only updated them if they're modified or if the updated attribute at the parent affects them. Give a try: update something at the parent and something else in one of the children, then call `SaveOrUpdate` at the parent. Everything should be updated.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing. I'm modifying a text property in the parent object and a text property in the child object. Only the parent object is updated when I call SaveOrUpdate

Comment: Ok, that's awkward. Could you provide some code?

Comment: Ah, I'm just being an idiot. I was updating a property that isn't actually mapped to a database field. It works just as you say. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I was just being stupid and updating a property that isn't mapped to any columns.

Looks like NH will update child records that need updating only.